# libgdx: STAGE : draw() method error in my render() method

Tags: nullpointerexception, libgdx, draw, stage

I cant fix this, I'm new to libgdx.

This is my render method.

```
@Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor(0.851f, 0.894f, 0.992f, 1f );
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        stage.draw();

        player.update();

        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(player.getCurrentFrame(), player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y);



        batch.end();
    }
```

This is where I declare my stage variable

```
stage= new Stage(new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));

            font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font.fnt"), false);
            style = new LabelStyle(font, Color.GREEN);
            label = new Label("Insert Text here", style);

            stage.addActor(label);
```

I got an error and my code is not working, i've try moving my "stage.draw();" but i still got same error. Error at

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.me.game.Game1.render(Game1.java:87)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Comment: what line is 87? Please add the `//this is line 87` to the code so that we know on what line is the problem.

Comment: I've already fix this. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @KingReinerAntonio very happy you fixed it. But you should share with us how you did it.